# Apache Beam: reading multiple files with beam.dataframe.io.read_csv returns _ReadFromPandas objects instead of dataframes

Tags: dataframe, apache-beam

I'm trying to read multiple csv files. Why is this code returning `<_ReadFromPandas(PTransform) label=[_ReadFromPandas]>`? Here's the read_csv code: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/_modules/apache_beam/dataframe/io.html

```
pcol_of_dfs = (p 
    | 'Match files' >> beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(path)
    | 'Read Files' >> beam.Map(lambda file_meta: beam.dataframe.io.read_csv(file_meta.path))
)
```

Ultimately I want to read all csv files and append the file names as additional column.

I have several hundreds of gzipped csv files in a GCS bucket. All of them have identical set of columns. All have headers. The csv values may contain line breaks. Files vary in size from a few kb to ~5GB.

Answer (score -1):

Per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe), to read multiple CSV files into a single Pandas DataFrame, you can use the `pandas.concat()` function instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'your_path_here' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```